# Is there a way to copy an entire Spreadsheet with only values and no formulas/links (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-sheets-api

The issue I am facing is trying to automate my weekly occurrence of coping an entire Spreadsheet to make a copy of it. Each week I need to hit "File --> Make a copy --> share with same people" and after doing so on the copy I need to hit "Allow Access" multiple times for each table that requires access, if I do not do this, there is no data displayed.

So I am wondering if there is a way to create a copy of a Spreadsheet where the copy contains entirely plain text and no formulas or links that way all the data can be read as soon as a copy is made.

This could be a separate question, but if anyone also knows how to automate hitting the "allow access" button for multiple tables in the copy that would also be helpful.

*To give an idea of the layout, essentially I have a main Spreadsheet (the one I make a copy of) that references data from other Spreadsheets (that are linked to google forms), and then I make a copy of the main Spreadsheet, and in making this copy is where I am required to hit the access button for each table.

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Trying to do this in python, might go a lil rough and use pythons mouse clicks based on position of the screen space. Not sure though need to look up more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).*

#### Code Example:

```
function duplicateSpreadsheet() {
  const idOfSheetToCopy = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ifOfSheetToCopy).next()
  const newFile = file.makeCopy()

  SpreadsheetApp.openById(newFile.getId()).getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    sheet.getDataRange().setValues(sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues())
  })
}
```

**Code Rundown:**

- Define Template Sheet ID
- Make a copy of the sheet using `DriveApp`
- Get the ID of the newly created sheet and open it with `SpreadsheetApp`
- Loop through all sheets in the new copy and replace all cell values for the cell's display value

Comment: This still doesn't resolve the issue of it coping the "#REF" showing up everywhere on the sheet. I'm going to try to create a copy then use your idea of copying each value into the copy. I'll hopefully update soon.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of pasting with "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>" use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>" for pasting without formatting. This will ignore things like links, font, and font size.

Not sure about the allow access button.

Comment: Thank you I know about this, the issue is I'm trying to automate this. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this without manually going in, and it would be as simple as doing a macro to ctrl-shift-v however when I create a copy, I need to first hit "allow access" on each table that is pulling from a link.